# How to select the sub attribute of CSS3 matrix transform with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, transform, css-transforms

My `.test` class looks like this:

```
.test {
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    width: 460px;
    height: 738px;
    transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 480.89px)
    matrix3d(-0.959423, 0.0701992, -0.273093, 0, 0, -0.968514, -0.248959, 0, 0.281971, 0.238857, -0.929215, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1)
    translate3d(230px, 369px, 0px);
}
```

Since `matrix3d` is dynamic, I'm trying to listen for changes of **the 3rd** array member of `matrix3d` and run a conditional if statement on it. How can this be done?

Comment: You mean you need this part - `0.281971, 0.238857, -0.929215, 0` from the value?

Comment: please show me how to gather all and how to gather each one, I would need to implement an IF function that would listen on those numbers if they are larger or smaller than what I decide, how do I do that. Is there another option other than split? I need the whole floating number, not 0, 1 and -1.

Comment: Oops, I didn't see the edit to your comment before posting the answer. What is wrong with split? It will give the full values (and not just 0 or 1). Check my answer and let me know if it doesn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `getComputedStyle` to get the value of the `transform` property and then split it (or use a  RegEx, whichever you prefer) to obtain the individual values like in the below snippet.

```js
var el = document.querySelector('.test'),
  op = document.querySelector('output'),
  btn = document.querySelector('.change'),
  oldparams, newparams;

window.onload = function() {

  /* get matrix on load */
  oldparams = getMatrix();
  op.innerHTML += 'Original Matrix Row 3: ' + oldparams[8] + ',' + oldparams[9] + ',' + oldparams[10] + ',' + oldparams[11]; /* since array is 0 based, 8 - 11 is the 3rd row. */

  /* on click of button, change matrix and get the changed value */
  btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
    el.style.transform = 'translate3d(0px, 0px, 480.89px) matrix3d(-0.959423, 0.0701992, -0.273093, 0, 0, -0.968514, -0.248959, 0, 0.383571, 0.578857, -0.639215, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1) translate3d(230px, 369px, 0px)';
    newparams = getMatrix();
    op.innerHTML += '<br><br> New Matrix Row 3: ' + newparams[8] + ', ' + newparams[9] + ', ' + newparams[10] + ', ' + newparams[11]; /* since array is 0 based, 8 - 11 is the 3rd row. */
  });
}

function getMatrix() {
  var matrix = window.getComputedStyle(el).transform;
  /*op.innerHTML = 'Matrix Transform is:' + matrix; */

  var params = matrix.split('(')[1].split(')')[0].split(',');
  return params;
}
```

```css
.test {
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  width: 460px;
  height: 738px;
  transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 480.89px) matrix3d(-0.959423, 0.0701992, -0.273093, 0, 0, -0.968514, -0.248959, 0, 0.281971, 0.238857, -0.929215, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1) translate3d(230px, 369px, 0px);
}
```

```html
<h2>Output</h2>
<output></output>
<button class='change'>Change Matrix</button>
<div class='test'>Some text</div>
```

Comment: I just tested it and this is the result:
http://prntscr.com/b9dadn
Pretty far away from what is needed, whats up with that floating div 'sometext', nice feature but far from what i need.

Comment: @erezT That `sometext` is the element with the transform. The array is 0 based and so it should work with 8-11 as index (refer updated answer) instead of the original 9-12. If it still doesn't satisfy your needs, can you show the exact output that you are looking for?

Comment: I already stated all in the opening post buddy.
To clarify again, I don't need the class to fly around, I just need each number of matrix3d stored dynamically as I would need to run if statmentets on them later.
Again - the view is dynamic, so when the view moves the numbers change, I want those numbers as variables that I can use as reference later.

Comment: @erezT: (a) There needs to be an element which has the 3d transform without which you cant find the values. (b) I have given you a sample, you'd have to adapt it such that you execute this piece of code whenever the matrix3d changes. That is the only way. There is no magic direct assignment into a variable.

Comment: So you're saying that I cannot dynamically store those values? How would I do that?

Comment: @erezT: Put the code that I have given into a function, make the function return the params, call the function say every x seconds (using `setInterval`) or call it whenever you need to check what the value is.

Comment: Can you please show a successful build for that and ill set as answer?

Comment: @erezT: I've updated the answer. The original matrix will be shown on load then click the button, it will change the matrix and show the revised values.

Comment: I see that, but I dont want to change the matrix, I just want the values at a certain point or time I wish to call them.

Comment: @erezT: I added a change only to show how the function can fetch the modified value even after a change. You can do the change whichever way you want (since you said your matrix3d is dynamic, there must be a change happening at some point or the other). Just call the function after the change happens (or when you want to get the new value) and it will give you the result.

Comment: I'll try it and let you know, if it works im setting the answer, thank you very much sir.

Comment: @erezT: If you are struggling to adapt it then can you post a fiddle of your code? Maybe I can help adapting it.

Comment: Hi Harry, here it is: https://jsfiddle.net/erezt/fjnhtvcu/1/     no need for the whole website, it's just pure JS

Comment: @erezT: Did you miss linking some libraries? I don't see anything at all in the output (and) where in this piece of code do you want my function to be incorporated?

Comment: but Harry, i'm not looking for display, there is nothing to display atm. I just need to know how to grab those values. There is nothing in my question that is asking about display.

Comment: Well then when exactly does your matrix change? Or where should I link this function to?

Comment: excellent, no need to link nothing, just show me with console.log() how you manage to select the matrix3d values.

Comment: @erezT: I have put the code where I think it should go (within the render function), but unless the cameraElement is ***in the page*** neither the set  transform (`cameraElement.style.transform`) nor the `getMatrix` function will work. The cameraElement must be in the page either by you manually adding it (or) by whatever library you are planning to use (three.js by any chance?).

Comment: Yes! I'm using three.js

Comment: @erezT: When will you call the CSS3DRenderer function? It seems to be having the necessary code to append the cameraElement to the document. Only after this call is made, the getMatrix function would output the values to the console.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113292/discussion-between-erezt-and-harry).